# Find the Domain of $\arcsin(\ln(\cosh(x^2)))$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I have gotten up to the inequality of $$e^{-1} \le \frac{e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2}}{2} \le e $$

Thank You

Comment: What's the minimum value of $\cosh$ ?

Comment: Did you start differentiating the function, or how did you end up with the expression with the $e^x$'s? I would start by noting
$$
1 \leq \cosh{x} \qquad \Rightarrow 1 \leq \cosh{x^2}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \qquad 0 \leq \ln{\cosh{x^2}}
$$
etc ...

Comment: @MattiP. OP's inequality comes from the domain restriction on $\arcsin$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the domain of the $\arcsin{}$ is $[-1,1],$ it follows that we want all $x$ such that $$-1\le \log\cosh x^2\le 1,$$ or exponentiating, we have $$e^{-1}\le \cosh x^2\le e.$$ In fact, we can make the lower bound tighter since we know that $\cosh y\ge 1$ for all real values of $y.$ Thus, we may write our domain as the set of all real $x$ satisfying the constraints $$2\le e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2}\le 2e,$$ or $$2e^{x^2} \le (e^{x^2})^2+1\le 2ee^{x^2}.$$ Now taking the first inequality and solving gives $$(e^{x^2})^2-2e^{x^2}+1=(e^{x^2}-1)^2\ge 0.$$ This implies $$e^{x^2}\ge 1,$$ or that $|x|\ge 0,$ which is true for all real $x.$

Thus taking the second inequality gives  $$e-\sqrt{e^2-1}\le e^{x^2}\le e+\sqrt{e^2-1},$$ or taking logarithms, $$\log \left(e-\sqrt{e^2-1}\right)\le x^2\le \log \left(e+\sqrt{e^2-1}\right).$$ Finally we must have $$\sqrt{\log \left(e-\sqrt{e^2-1}\right)}\le |x|\le \sqrt{\log \left(e+\sqrt{e^2-1}\right)}.$$

Recall that we must also have that $|x|\ge 0.$ Thus, it follows that the domain is the set of real $x$ so that (since the leftmost quantity is imaginary) $$|x|\le \sqrt{\log \left(e+\sqrt{e^2-1}\right)}.$$

This is reasonable since your function is even.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the second inequality simplified?

Comment: @johnadams12 It also involves a quadratic in $e^{x^2}.$ So just apply the quadratic formula to find the roots, which helps to factor the quadratic.

Comment: Why we need $x>0$?

Comment: @user From solving the first inequality in the *system* we deduce that $x\ge 0.$

Comment: Note that $e^{x^2}\ge 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @user Hmm. I see your point. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Now it seems fine, even if I can’t see the needing to use $\log $ function and not directly the $\cosh^{-1}$ which is much simpler.

Comment: @user It's simply an outfall of my calculations. I don't see much point in writing it as a hyperbolic cosine, given that the logarithm is more ubiquitous.

Answer (score 1):

We need

- $\cosh(x^2)>0$

which always holds since $\cosh(x)\ge 1$ and

- $-1\le \log(\cosh(x^2))\le 1$

which requires $\frac1e \le \cosh(x^2)\le e\implies 0 \le \cosh(x^2)\le e $ therefore the domain is

$$ -\sqrt{\cosh^{-1} e} \le x \le \sqrt{\cosh^{-1} e}$$

Answer (score 1):

You must have:
$$e^{-1} \le \frac{e^{x^\color{red}2} + e^{-x^\color{red}2}}{2} \le e \Rightarrow \\
e^{-1}<1\stackrel{AM-GM}<\frac{e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2}}{2}\le e \Rightarrow \\
(e^{x^2})^2-2ee^{x^2}+1\le 0 \Rightarrow \\
e-\sqrt{e^2-1}\le e^{x^2}\le e+\sqrt{e^2-1} \Rightarrow \\
\ln (e-\sqrt{e^2-1})<0\le x^2\le \ln (e+\sqrt{e^2-1}) \Rightarrow \\
|x|\le \sqrt{\ln(e+\sqrt{e^2-1})} \Rightarrow \\
-\sqrt{\ln (e+\sqrt{e^2-1}})\le x\le \sqrt{\ln (e+\sqrt{e^2-1}}) \ \ \text{or} \\
-\sqrt{\cosh^{-1}(e)}\le x\le \sqrt{\cosh^{-1}(e)}.$$